# 'TranslationServiceClient' object has no attribute 'location_path' on Google Cloud Translate "translate_v3"

Tags: python-3.x, google-translate, google-cloud-translate

I'm using Python 3.6 and google-cloud-translate package.

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3 as translate
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient(credentials = credentials)
parent = client.location_path("my-location", "global")
```

Since yesterday, having updated the libraries I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'TranslationServiceClient' object has no attribute 'location_path'
```

Is it that these libraries have changed? What is the right way to channel this inquiry?

Answer (score 7):

Also encountered this. Not all the documentation has been updated yet, but they have published a migration guide:

https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/UPGRADING.html

You could replace `parent` with `"projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<LOCATION>"`

or define

```py
def location_path(project_id, location):
    # might as well use an f-string, the new library supports python >=3.6
    return f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"
```

and change `client.location_path` to `location_path` if this is something you use in many locations.

There are more sweeping changes, too. They now prefer you to pass a dictionary called `request` to the API methods, although the old way is still accepted. Thus, your code might look like this:

```py
from google.cloud import translate_v3 as translate

client = translate.TranslationServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

response = client.translate_text(
    request={
        "parent": "projects/my-location/locations/global",
        "target_language_code": target_language_code,
        "contents": [text],
    }
)
```

Now, you might well ask 'how will I know what to put in that request dictionary?'. It looks as though the library comes with type annotations for the dictionaries appropriate for each method: https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/translate_v3/types.html

For example, I read in your comment on another answer that you have had trouble with the `detect_language` method. The method signature indicates that if you use keyword arguments, `content` should be a valid one, so I don't know why that fails - maybe it's a bug.

However, if instead you use a `request` dictionary, that should look [like this](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/translate_v3/types.html#google.cloud.translate_v3.types.DetectLanguageRequest). You'll see that the keys don't appear to correspond exactly to the method signature keywords (although `content` is one of them).

This code would work:

```py
response = client.detect_language({
    "parent": "projects/my-location/locations/global",
    "content": "Tá Gaeilge Agam, ach tá mé i mo chonai i Sasana",
})

lang = response.languages[0].language_code
```

(the return type is somewhat convoluted, as you can see)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I got rid of the 'parent' code all together and added it inside of the translate_text method.

```
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

response = client.translate_text(
              parent = 'projects/{}'.format(project_id),
              contents = [text],
              mime_type = 'text/plain',
              source_language_code = 'en-US',
              target_language_code = 'es')
```

Documentation:
https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/translate_v3/services.html

Comment: It seems to work but - still getting more errors from this new release. Have you been able to solve this other error: TypeError: detect_language() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content'

Answer (score 0):

There nothing going to work out **if python version is 3.6 or 3.8** I have **fixed** this easily by **upgrading to python3.10** then **upgrade the other google packages**

```
    google-api-core==2.7.1
    google-auth==2.6.4
    google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
    google-cloud-core==2.3.0
    google-cloud-translate==3.7.2
    google-cloud-vision==2.7.2
    google-pasta==0.2.0
    googleapis-common-protos==1.56.0
    grpcio==1.44.0
    grpcio-status==1.44.0
```